# Bash que ejecute curl

Tags: bash, archivo, shell, curl

Cómo crear un bash del tipo filewatcher que cuando un archivo como "**FILE_RECEIVED.CSV**" llegue a un directorio local "C:/directory/", ejecute un curl (método GET) que contenga el nombre  de ese archivo recibido.
El curl sería algo como esto:

curl http://localhos:3030/load/process-file?filename=**FILE_RECEIVED.CSV**&filePathFile=C:/directory/

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ];
then
    echo "especificar un directorio como argumento"
    echo "$0 <dir>"
    exit 1
fi

while true;
do
    for a in $(ls -1 $1/* 2>/dev/null);
    do
        curl "http://localhost:3000/load/process-file?filename=art_2021_inv.csv&filePathFile=C:/Users/mgarc/repo/"
    done
    sleep 2s
done

executar:
./filewatcher_curl.sh <directorio>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto en base a lo que has intentado? No vamos a resolver el problema por ti.